# 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have trained a model on colab using artifical neural network (keras) and in the end I want to save it but getting error. I have tried pydrive method also. I have all the required library previously when I run it on local computer it worked.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json

 model = Sequential()                                      # create model
 model.add(Dense(6, input_dim = 8, activation = 'relu'))
 model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))                  # hidden layer
 model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))               # output layer
 model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)

def build_classifier():

    model = Sequential()                                      # create model
    model.add(Dense(6, input_dim = 8, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation = 'relu'))                  # hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))               # output layer
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
return model  

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = model,X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)

model.save("model.h5")
```

but getting error 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'save'. does google colab required different method to save model?

[image]

Comment: The code and the error message does not match, the model variable is a Sequential but the error says differently (its a KerasClassifier), so please make sure that the code is correct and produces the same error message.

Comment: I have edited code, crossvalidation part is added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'save'

Error occur because I tried to save KerasClassifier(**Cross-validation function**) Since the **The purpose of cross-validation is model checking, not model building.** So after changing parameter model will be saved.Thanks @MatiasValdenegro for insight.

Better explanation available at

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/how-to-choose-a-predictive-model-after-k-fold-cross-validation